# connecting to Dynamodb from iOS (Swift) using AWS Amplify

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify

I used to directly connect to access to Dynamodb table from iOS using AWS mobile SDK. Now AWS encourages to migrate to Amplify. in the documentation there is no guideline for Dynamodb read/write operations. Should we use API to access to Dynamodb or can we use AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/mobile-hub-add-aws-mobile-nosql-database.html)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm mistaken, because I'm new at this, I believe we have to use the [REST API](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/ios/api#rest-api) in order to make our calls to various AWS services in an Amplify context. So a Lambda function would perform your DynamoDB accesses.

**UPDATE**
When you add the REST API you will be asked what kind of function template you want to use. The first option is:

> CRUD function for Amazon DynamoDB table (Integration with Amazon API Gateway and Amazon DynamoDB)